# C++ why is file pattern matching returning the following incorrect file type: .tif$$$ScandAllPRO$$$

Tags: c++, file, visual-studio-2010, pattern-matching, console-application

The file pattern I am using:`wchar_t* pdf_tif = L"/*.??f\0";` should only return .pdf or .tif file types. Somehow it is returning the following incorrect file types: .tif$$$ScandAllPRO$$$ can anyone offer a reason why this might be? As well as a solution to avoid returning these incorrect file types.

an example:

//S001E002/Some Folder/some_subfolder/NO PO_2016-04-130225.tif$$$ScandAllPRO$$$

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{  
    std::wstring ap(L"//S001E002/Some Folder/");
    wchar_t* pdf_tif = L"/*.??f\0";
    std::wstring all(L"*");
    std::wstring temp = ap + all;
    const wchar_t* Hotels = temp.c_str();

    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    std::vector<std::wstring> folders;
    std::vector<std::wstring> vs;
    HANDLE hFind;

    std::wcout << "Hotels Folder directory: " << Hotels << "\n";

    hFind = FindFirstFile(Hotels, &FindFileData);
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    {
        do 
        {
            if(FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & _A_SUBDIR)
            {
                temp = FindFileData.cFileName;
                if ( wcscmp(temp.c_str(), L".") == 0 ||  wcscmp(temp.c_str(), L"..") == 0 ) { continue; }
                else
                {                       
                    folders.push_back(FindFileData.cFileName);
                    std::wcout << "Folder: " << FindFileData.cFileName << "\n";                 
                }
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData));
        FindClose(hFind);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < folders.size(); i++)
    {
        //folders[i]
        temp = ap + folders[i] + pdf_tif;
        const wchar_t* _files = temp.c_str();
        std::wcout << "File Directory: " << _files << "\n";
        hFind = FindFirstFile(_files, &FindFileData);
        if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
        {
            do 
            {   
                temp = FindFileData.cFileName;
                if ( wcscmp(temp.c_str(), L".") == 0 ||  wcscmp(temp.c_str(), L"..") == 0 ) {continue;}
                else
                {
                    temp = ap + folders[i] + L"/" + FindFileData.cFileName;
                    std::wcout << temp.c_str() << "\n";
                    vs.push_back(temp); 
                }                   
            } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData));
            FindClose(hFind);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP, why was ScandAll Pro adding that ($$$ScandAllPRO$$$) to the end of the file extension in the first place?
I am seeing the same problem intermittently and don't know what to do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wchar_t* pdf_tif = L"/*.??f\0";
```

Not related to your question, but you don't need to add `'\0'` at the end of the string. It is done automatically for you (it's sometimes required for example when working with arrays, but not here)

For finding specific extensions, when there is more than one, the reliable method is to change the wild card to `wchar_t* pdf_tif = L"/*";` this will list all the files. Then you can examine the extension of each file. To get the extension, you can use `PathFindExtension`

```
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi") //Visual Studio specific pragma for including libs

...
std::wstring ext = PathFindExtension(FindFileData.cFileName);
if (ext != L".tif" && ext != L".pdf")
    continue;
```

While you are at it, you can add a recursive function so that it finds not just the folders in the directory, but also the sub folders of sub folders if any. Example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi")

void find_subfolders(std::vector<std::wstring> &vec, std::wstring dir)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fd = { 0 };
    std::wstring wildcard = dir + L"*";
    HANDLE hfind = FindFirstFile(wildcard.c_str(), &fd);
    if (hfind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return;
    do
    {
        if (wcscmp(fd.cFileName, L".") == 0 || wcscmp(fd.cFileName, L"..") == 0)
            continue;

        if (fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            std::wstring path = dir + fd.cFileName + L"\\";
            vec.push_back(path);

            //uncomment this if you want all directories in the tree
            //find_subfolders(sa, path);
        }

    } while (FindNextFile(hfind, &fd));

    FindClose(hfind);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> folders;
    std::vector<std::wstring> vs;

    find_subfolders(folders, L"\\S001E002\\Some Folder\\");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < folders.size(); i++)
    {
        WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
        std::wstring wildcard = folders[i] + L"\\*";
        HANDLE hfind = FindFirstFile(wildcard.c_str(), &fd);
        if (hfind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            do
            {
                if (wcscmp(fd.cFileName, L".") == 0 || wcscmp(fd.cFileName, L"..") == 0)
                    continue; 

                std::wstring ext = PathFindExtension(fd.cFileName);

                //convert extension to lower case
                for (size_t k = 0; k < ext.size(); k++) 
                    ext[k] = towlower(ext[k]);

                if (ext == L".tif" || ext == L".tiff" || ext == L".pdf")
                    vs.push_back(folders[i] + fd.cFileName);

            } while (FindNextFile(hfind, &fd));

            FindClose(hfind);
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vs.size(); i++)
        std::wcout << vs[i] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```